# Formula to calculate number of arrangments with fixed number in it met one or more times

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a simple formula to solve this task:

It’s know that there are $5^5 = 3125$ ways we can arrange digits from $1$ to $5$ with repetitions. How to calculate number of such arrangements where one specific digit is met one or more times? For example, we are interested in counting all arrangements where digit $1$ is met at least once: $12345, 11234, 11134,$ etc.

How about number of arrangements where digits $1$ and $2$ both met? Like $12345, 11223$, but not $11345$ or $22345$.

Number of arrangements where all digits $1, 2$ and $3$ are met?

Does common formula exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of this question as:

number of arrangements where digit x is met at least once = number of ways to arrange digits from 1 to 5 - number of arrangements where digit x is not met

For example, to calculate arrangements where digit 1 is met at least once, you could subtract number of arrangements where digit 1 is not met from total number of arrangements. (i.e. $5^5-4^5$)

Another example, to calculate arrangements where both 1 and 2 are met, you could subtract number of arrangements where digit 1 and 2 are not met from total number of arrangements. (i.e. $5^5-3^5$)

So, I think a "common formula" would be $y^n-(y-x)^n$, where y is the total number of digits you can choose, n is the number of digits in the arrangement and x is the number of digits you want to include in the arrangement.

Hope that helps!